# Executing script on a remote server

Tags: vb.net, powershell

The following code works when the script is executed on the current machine
(Currently, the script is a simple messagebox displaying the argument passed)

```
Arguments:

UserName = Nothing
Password = Nothing
RemoteMachineName = "CurrentMachineName"
PathBashFile = "Path/To/My/Local/Script.ps1"
Params = "parameter1"
```

However, when I want to run a local script on a remote computer, the script is **never** actually executed. The code doesn't throw any exception.

```
Arguments:

UserName = "MyUsername"
Password = "MyPassword"
RemoteMachineName = "RemoteMachineName"
PathBashFile = "Path/To/My/Local/Script.ps1"
Params = "parameter1"
```

All I have as a result is :

```
outParams("processId") = Nothing
outParams("returnValue") = 8
```

What's going on? Why isn't my script running as expected on the remote machine? (No message box pops up on either machine. I have tried other cmdlets, but none ever work)

Here is the code:

```
Try
    connOptions = New ConnectionOptions()
    connOptions.Username = UserName
    connOptions.Password = Password

    connOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate
    connOptions.Authentication = Management.AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy

    managementPath = New ManagementPath("\\" & RemoteMachineName & "\root\cimv2:Win32_Process")

    Scope = New ManagementScope(managementPath, connOptions)
    Scope.Connect()
    objectGetOptions = New ObjectGetOptions()
    processClass = New ManagementClass(Scope, New ManagementPath("root\cimv2:Win32_Process"), objectGetOptions)

    inParams = processClass.GetMethodParameters("Create")
    inParams("CommandLine") = "cmd.exe /c powershell """ & PathBashFile & """ " & params
    inParams("CurrentDirectory") = workingDirectoryPath
    outParams = processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, Nothing)
    MsgBox(outParams("processId") & "   " & outParams("returnValue"))

Catch ex As Exception
    Throw New Exception("[ExecuteRemoteBashFile] " & ex.Message)
End Try
```

If someone could point out any mistakes in my code, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you have required privs, and user rights assigned (eg Execute Batch Script" or similar) on the remote machine? (I'm not sure if not having these would cause an exception to be thrown in this instance or not, to be honest... I would have thought so, but figured I should suggest it just in case...)

Comment: Well, if I run the script locally on the other server, it works perfectly

Comment: Why don't you use WS-management (considering you are using Powershell v2 at least) ? you will avoid dealing with WMI directly.   Check http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff700227.aspx

Comment: the `PathBashFile` variable of the script should be the path as seen **from the server**, meaning when logged interactively on the server, doing `dir PathBashFile` should be OK.

Comment: @MatM I've tried putting the script in a shared folder, but nothing happens anyway. I've also tried setting the executionpolicy to Unrestricted, still no result.

Comment: @Msonic could you try to set your command to "cmd.exe /C dir """ & PathBashFile & "">C:\mydirtest.txt". It will show you that the command executes and script is readable. Could you confirm ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by putting the complete path to powershell.exe, instead of assuming that the console knows where to look for that...

```
inParams("CommandLine") = "cmd.exe /c C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v2.0\powershell.exe """ & PathBashFile & """ " & params
```